# What's the Python equivalent to JavaScript's Promise.resolve?

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrent.futures

#### `Promise` in Javascript

As in MDN document:

> The Promise.resolve() method "resolves" a given value to a Promise. If the value is a promise, that promise is returned; if the value is a thenable, Promise.resolve() will call the then() method with two callbacks it prepared; otherwise the returned promise will be fulfilled with the value.

It's useful when you need to handle a value whose type is either `T` or `Promise<T>`, you can always choose to `const promiseValue = Promise.resolve(value)` and just treat it as promise afterward.

#### Example: What I want

Suppose there is a value: `Union[T, Future[T]]` , and I want to convert it to just `Future` type. In JavaScript I can just `value = Promise.resolve(value)`, but I don't know what's the suggested way to do it in Python.

#### Questions

Though I can always choose to build one by myself, I am just wondering if Python have a build-in method to do the same thing for `Future`?

And also what's the suggested way to handle such situation without `Promise.resolve` in Python?

Comment: Interesting question. I added your comment to the question. What was your research - did you stumble upon [javascript - Differences between Futures in Python3 and Promises in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47493369/differences-between-futures-in-python3-and-promises-in-es6/47499994#47499994) as helpful ?

Comment: I think python uses a different philosophy to deal with Future. I thought the `add_done_callback`  of `Future` is equivalent to `Promise.then` in ,  but it turns out just a listener pattern, which makes future un-chainable. Thus this question become kind of useless, unless Python have the `Promise.then` mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I use Observable instead of Future/Promise. ReactiveX is a more general pattern to handle asynchronous operations. Observable to future/promise is like list to scalar value. And the equvalent of `Promise.resolve(value)` in RxPY is `reactivex.just(value)`.